# With loop to sort worksheet with dynamic filter

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to dynamic filter a workbook and export a specific column to a new workbook with the filter still applied.

All cells with text in them need to be selected so I used ".usedRange".

Why is my code returning error (see attached image)? Is there something wrong with my definitions at the top of the code?

[image]

```
Sub KPI_Data()

    
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim BOM As Workbook
'
    'Adding New Workbook
   Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
  ' variable for the bom workbook
    Set BOM = ThisWorkbook
  
 ' Dynamic filter BOM sheet
 
    With BOM.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criterial:="2"
    End With

... etc

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add the code as text to your post. `.UsedRange` needs to be applied to a worksheet, not to a workbook, e.g.: `BOM.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 It works now! Thank you for the clarification. New VBA coder here, I appreciate it